# GDK: Is there a way I can get if an arbitrary keyval or mouse button is down during a GdkEvent, or to see what GdkModifierType bits map?

Tags: c, gtk, gdk

(I asked a similar, unanswered question (only a X11-specific comment) months ago specifically pertaining to the Alt key; I have since refactored my requirements.)

I'd like to be able to see if the Alt key or if mouse buttons 8 or 9 are held at the time of an event in GDK, typically `GdkEventButton`, `GdkEventMotion`, and `GdkEventKey`, in the same fashion as the GdkModifierType state field in the various events.

However, the Alt key isn't automatically exported by GDK, as the Super, Hyper, and Meta keys are. Instead, the documentation merely states that MOD1 is typically the Alt key and that only mouse buttons 1-5 are explicitly supported. "pbor" suggested on IRC that all programs merely assume MOD1 is Alt, but I'd rather not make those kinds of assumptions, and that still doesn't help with the mouse buttons.

So my question is: is there a way I can detect these keys and buttons being pressed at the time of an event? For instance:

- is there a way I can hand GDK a keysym and get out a GdkModifierType back? I see that there are ways to do the other way around and that require a hardware keycode...
- is there an equivalent to the Windows API `GetKeyState()` function, which specifically returns the key state at the time of the message being processed, regardless of what is being held at the time of the call?

No code sample this time, sorry. Thanks.

Comment: I would listen to pbor's advice, and only reconsider it if you actually encounter a system where the assumption doesn't hold...

Comment: I suppose I can do that, but that still doesn't help with the other mouse buttons...

Comment: Very late update... pbor is more right than previously thought; GtkAccelGroup requires that MOD1 be Alt, so I'm just going with that. That still leaves BUTTON8/9...

Comment: https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gdk/x11/gdkdevice-xi2.c#n763 nope :( (via mclasen) Thanks anyway!